# How to view screenshot in terminal with rspec and rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am following this [tutorial](https://mdominiak.com/2017/12/28/rspec-system-specs.html) to test system specs with rails 5.1. If I deliberately fail a test, I get the following output in the terminal

```
 WARN: Screenshot could not be saved. `page.current_path` is empty.
    F


  Failures:

      1) Homepage shows greeting
         Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'Hello Worlds'
           expected to find text "Hello Worlds" in "Hello World"

         [Screenshot]: tmp/screenshots/failures_r_spec_example_groups_homepage_shows_greeting_506.png



         # ./spec/spec/system/home_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The file specified for the screenshot exists, but the screen shot is not shown in the terminal.  I can open the screen shot manually, so it is being generated correctly.

If I type `chromedriver --version` I get

```
ChromeDriver 2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef)
```

and I am using version  63.0.3239.132 of Chrome.

How do I get the screenshots to open in terminal on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 4):

Screenshot display depends on what kind of terminal you use and `RAILS_SYSTEM_TESTING_SCREENSHOT` environment variable.

For build-in terminal:

```
ENV['RAILS_SYSTEM_TESTING_SCREENSHOT'] = 'artifact'
```

For iTerm2:

```
ENV['RAILS_SYSTEM_TESTING_SCREENSHOT'] = 'inline'
```

Comment: I am using the standard Terminal, and I tried this, putting ```ENV['RAILS_SYSTEM_TESTING_SCREENSHOT'] = 'artifact'``` in config/application.rb, and this did not help.

Comment: I tried in a different app, and I get an additional warning stating ``` WARN: Screenshot could not be saved. `page.current_path` is empty.```. This despite the screen shot file actually being saved.  I have edited the original question to add this information.